# Can I share games between two PS4 systems with the new Family account?

Tags: ps4, psn

The PS4 5.00 software update adds family accounts, replacing sub accounts.
On my iPhone, the family account means I can share apps with my family - I buy the apps, they can download for free.
I recently bought a PS4 pro, it's in the living room, and the kids got the old PS4 box.
Currently, my "primary account" is on the kids box, otherwise they can't play anything using their account, right now - they can't play in the living room, because it only works if I'm signed in (and there's no way I'm letting them ruin my saves).
Does this new update offer any remedy?
Has anything changed with the new family account addition or is it just a simple expansion of the former "sub accounts" method?
I know how the old method works (or *doesn't work*, to be more precise), I'm asking if anything's changed with it.
Not even talking about the plus account, the kids are too little to be playing online anyway (I have a plus account, if it makes any difference).